How to take out hours from d hr m s in excel?
I have a column in excel as "2 d 9 hr 29 m 37 s" and I just want the total time in hours so the output should be 57.49.
The below formula works well until there is a cell with just seconds e.g. "30 s" as it seems to be interpreted as minutes instead of seconds e.g the value will be "0.5" when it should be "0.0833". How do I amend the below formula so that seconds only cells are correctly calculated?
=(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1),0)+ IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("hr",A1)),"","00:")&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("d",A1),-1)+2,LEN(A1)),"hr ",":"),"m ",":"),"s",""))) * 24 

You can use the following formula:


=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(
 MID(0 & A1,SEARCH({" d"," h"," m"," s"},0 & A1) - 2,2),
 {0,0,0,0})),{86400,3600,60,1}) / 3600



Note: days with time are stored as a single floating point value in Excel.
I suggest you use the Excel internal format to store all time and date values; it simply is a lot easier. It allows calculations, picking out parts and reformatting the values for displaying.
So:
Set A1=2.39556712962963
Then =A1*24 will display how many hours that is (57.4936111111111)
And =INT(A1) &"d "& TEXT(A1-INT(A1),"HH:MM:SS") will display 2d 09:29:37
Yet further =TEXT(A1-INT(A1),"HH") will display the hours only (09).
Oh, one more "note":
https://www.google.com/search?q=what+every+programmer+should+know+about+floating+point

Comment moved into answer.
